Find all modules over $F[[x]]$, that are 4-dimensional vector space over $F$.
I try to understand how to solve this problem:
Find all modules over $F[[x]]$, that are 4-dimensional vector space over $F$.
I know that if $V$ is vector space over $F$, then $V$ is $F[x]$-module with some fixed linear operator $\varphi$, but it seems unuseful here. The key problem is to understand what restrictions on $F[[x]]$-module need to be applied, to make it 4-dimensional vector space over $F$.

You probably want to consider continuous $F[\![x]\!]$-modules. A continuous $F[\![x]\!]$-module $V$ is a ring homomorphism $F[\![x]\!]\to End_F(V)$ continuous with respect to the $x$-adic topology on $F[\![x]\!]$ and the discrete topology on $End(V)$. One can prove this factors through $F[x]/(x^N)$ for some $N\gg0$. In other words, a continuous $F[\![x]\!]$-module $V$ is a $F$-vector space $V$ together with a nilpotent endomorphism $x\colon V\to V$. Such homomorphisms are classified by the size of the Jordan blocks.
So there are $5$ modules of dimension $4$: corresponding to $4$, $3+1$, $2+2$, $2+1+1$, and $1+1+1+1$.

Thanks, i think i got idea of answer, it is natural, but i steel don't understand the argumentation. This is first time i see notation of continuous module and my english is not good, so maybe because of that i can't understand what do you meant by saying:
One can prove this factors through $F[x]/(x^N)$ for some $N\gg0$.
Why big N is needed? I know structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID, and because of $V$ is finite dimension the $V$ is isomorphic to sum of cyclic factor-groups of base ring, but from where you get $F[x]/(x^N)$? Can you write what book i need to read?

Because $F[![x]!]$ is an inverse limit of $F[x]/(x^N)$.

I appreciate your answer, but i think there is a way to use few words and notations to prove it (in my course there is no notations of continuous modules, x-adic topology and inverse limits).
